# Scrape webpage when it throws an ASP.NET error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to scrape a webpage when it throws a "potentially dangerous script" error. Everytime I do this, I  get a server 500 but I can scrape a normal, operating page. Is there a way I can scrape a webpage when it throws an error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [ASP.NET health monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998306.aspx)? There's a mail provider that will automatically send the error details to you without any manual scraping and you can configure it all with just some config file entries. Easy!

Comment: I was hoping to do everything without editing the app in question but I guess I will use that now :)

Comment: Keep in mind that all you're editting is the config file. No code behind, no recompile, no re-deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but maybe the error thrown, triggers a server error (500)? That would make sense. You should be still able to get the *output* from the page.

Generally though, and I hope you don't mind, I'd have to object to your error handling. First off, you could put the error in a log and use a tool to monitor it for errors. Secondly, if your *script* throws an exception, you could hand it off to a service like [Exceptional](http://getexceptional.com/), which in turn notifies you.

Comment: Hi, I don't mind your comments :) I was hoping for a way to do the above without using any error logging. My code is as follows:

      HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(currentUrl);


            HttpWebResponse response =  (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

At the response, it is null and the exception comes up. I can't get any details about it. I get the same problem with webclient etc. The url is the url of the search page with the querystring (what user entered in text box).

Comment: I'm not enough familiar with ASP to be of real help. Aside from the 'error', do you get an error message though? If so, what is it.

Comment: Just the standard "A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (culprit script here)."

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) to log all errors. You'll get lots of useful additional information also.

More details at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479332.aspx 
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx